# Python: None value when returning from function

Tags: python, function, variables, return, nonetype

I'm writing a program that stores 3 players and their scores in a list and then prints them out at the end. Simple stuff really, however I'm trying to call the value for the player score from a function called playerscore() which prevents you from entering a score >5.

this works fine when you run through it with the correct value, but if you input an incorrect value > 5 then it begins the playerscore function again and allows for a new value to be entered but returns "None"

```python
teamlist = []

def playercreator():
    counter=0
    while counter < 3:
        name = playername()
        score = playerscore()
        print(score) #check - this one goes wrong when returned after the if/else in playerscore()
        teamlist.append(name+" "+str(score))
        counter = counter + 1

def playername():
    name=input("What name do you want for your player?\n")
    return (name)

def playerscore():
    global teamtotal
    score=input("input score?\n")
    print(score) #check
    if int(score)>5:
        print("Your attack score must be between 0 and 5")
        print(score) #check
        playerscore()
    else:
        return int(score)

playercreator()

for x in teamlist:
    print(x)
```

for example, these are the inputs and outputs:

```
What name do you want for your player?
p1
input score?
3
What name do you want for your player?
p2
input score?
6
Your attack score must be between 0 and 5
input score?
5
What name do you want for your player?
p3
input score?
2

p1 3
p2 None
p3 2
```

I feel like there's something obvious that i'm missing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a return statement in the if block (when the score is greater than 5):

```
def playerscore():
    global teamtotal
    score=input("input score?\n")
    if int(score)>5:
        print("Your attack score must be between 0 and 5")        
        return playerscore()
    else:
        return int(score)
```

Output:

```
What name do you want for your player?
shovon
input score?
2
2
What name do you want for your player?
sorida
input score?
23
Your attack score must be between 0 and 5
input score?
43
Your attack score must be between 0 and 5
input score?
234
Your attack score must be between 0 and 5
input score?
1
1
What name do you want for your player?
shody
input score?
2
2
shovon 2
sorida 1
shody 2
```

From [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions):

> In fact, even functions without a return statement do return a value, albeit a rather boring one. This value is called None (it’s a built-in name).

Comment: It's that simple! I knew that it had to be something like that but I completely forgot to return if it didn't meet the criteria as well as if it did. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing this:

```
if int(score)>5:
    playerscore()
```

you call `playerscore` function without `return` statement. This produces `None` value.

Answer (score 1):

The type of recursion you're trying to do with your code will work with a small correction on your code... which follows:

```
def playerscore():
global teamtotal
score=input("input score?\n")
print(score) #check
if int(score)>5:
    print("Your attack score must be between 0 and 5")
    print(score) #check
    return playerscore()
else:
    return int(score)
```

You can notice that this time, we returned `playerscore()`. As it seems like you're learning the basics, I'd like to propose a slightly different approach, as you'll get a ValueError exception if the player types a string (some letters) instead of a number. You can keep using your recursive function in the exception catch, and use a while loop to make the player to keep the number within your desired range. Here follows my suggestion to prevent the ValueError exception:

```
def playerscore():
global teamtotal
score=input("input score?\n")
try:
    while int(score) < 0 or int(score) > 5:
        print("Your attack score must be between 0 and 5")
        print(score)  # check
        score = input("input score?\n")
except ValueError:
    print("Your attack score must be A NUMBER between 0 and 5")
    return playerscore()
return int(score)
```

I hope that helps. Regards.

Comment: This is great. I hadn't got this far yet but had initially planned to catch errors. Thank you for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

When function doesn't return anything, value will be `None`.

So you should check your code for the case where `score` is larger than 5. (Compare it to the case where score is *not* larger than five.)